# why nodejs server returned 404 status code in bad request

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend

I can't understand why the server returns the 404 status error code if the wrong route is registered.
The server should return 400 status error code.
I would like to know what this may be related to.

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wVSK.png)

Comment: Because its normal that you receive 404 if an resource cannnot be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code 404 (not found) is used whenever a resource cannot be found. 
Since your route is not registered and does not exist you will receive 404

Answer (score 0):

This means that Postman cannot find /api/users/register. You should attach the API definition as well as the server definition